# Listen when videoview controll appears/disapears

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

Basicly, I want to detect when controll overlay appears and dissapears over videoview. I sow a lot of different callback on mediacontroller, unfrtunatly, I didnot recognized suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override MediaController Show and Hide methods

```
class MyMediaController extends MediaController{

    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Showing the media controller");
        super.show();
    }

    public void hide(){
        System.out.println("Hiding the media controller");
        super.hide();
    }


}
```

I can't test this right now but it should work